# approximating Euler’s number e to within 0.001 in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to write an algorithm that approximates e using a while loop and returns the number of terms needed to approximate the number.
It seems to me like the loop stops after the first iteration but I cannot figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
import math

def factorial(n):
    f = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        f = f * i
    return f

def e_to_x_series():
    sum_acc = 0
    e = math.e
    i = 1
    print(e)
    while abs(e - sum_acc) < 0.001:
        sum_acc = sum_acc + 1 ** i / factorial(i)
        print(sum_acc)
        i += 1
    return sum_acc

print(e_to_x_series())
```

Comment: Are you saying your code isn't working? How do you know? See how to create a [mcve], and edit the question.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "<" should be changed to ">" in your while loop.